# I can sort on ISODate attributes, but the "$lt" and "$gt" queries are failing in my MongoDB Collections

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query, pymongo, mongodb-atlas

I am centralizing data on my Atlas Cluster from bare-metal servers running community MongoDB databases locally. However I have an issue with my `ISODates()` attributes that are converted to `"$date"` dictionaries, after which the sort() query still works but the "$lt" and "$gt" queries are failing.

Attribute in local db

```
"createdTime": ISODate("2023-01-20T11:20:50.268Z")
```

Attribute in the Atlas Cluster'db :

```
 "createdTime" : { '$date': '2023-01-20T11:20:50.268Z' }
```

In my Atlas Cluster's collection, I am still able to sort on the time attribute :

```
db.MyCollection.find().sort({createdTime:-1}).map(x => x.createdTime)
[
  { '$date': '2023-01-20T11:20:50.268Z' },
  { '$date': '2023-01-20T11:20:26.587Z' },
  { '$date': '2023-01-20T11:20:04.108Z' },
]
```

But when I try to use the operators `"$gt"` and `"$lt"` then mongo doesn't know what to do :

```
db.MyCollection.countDocuments({ createdTime: { $lt: ISODate("2023-02-01T00:00:00.000Z")} })
0
// even with "$date" as a key
db.MyCollection.countDocuments({ "createdTime.$date": { $lt: ISODate("2023-02-01T00:00:00.000Z")}})
0
```

Eventually, I figured I could make it work with a Javascript function to convert the "$date" objects back to ISODate, but I want to be able to use the "$lt" and "$gt" in my Python API, relying on pymongo.

Pymongo code :

```
res = db["MyCollection"].count_documents({"createdTime": {"$lt": datetime.now() }})
# res = 0
```

Any idea how I could solve what I assume is a date formatting issue?

Comment: Same issue here and also for filtering, it doesn't work either

Comment: What python code have you tried? Can you add this to your question.

Comment: At a guess I would say that the way you are adding data to Atlas is incorrect. If you run a `db.MyCollection.findOne()` on Atlas it should give the same output as your local example, e.g. `createdTime: ISODate("2023-01-20T11:20:50.268Z")`.

Comment: Also generally where you see `'$date'` ,`'$oid'` etc is from the output of a BSON to JSON type converter, e.g. `json.dumps()` or mongoexport. You don't want to store JSON in mongo you need to retain the BSON types.

Comment: Would you show the code you used to create the Atlas collection?

Comment: `ISODate("2023-01-20T11:20:50.268Z")` is the same as `{ '$date': '2023-01-20T11:20:50.268Z' }`, it is just a different display format. `ISODate` is used by mongo shell `mongosh` and `$date` is the [MongoDB Extended JSON](https://www.mongodb.com/docs/manual/reference/mongodb-extended-json/#mongodb-bsontype-Date) format.

Comment: @WernfriedDomscheit I wonder if through the method of creating the Atlas collection, `'$date'` is actually a literal rather than Extended JSON.

Answer (score 1):

Firstly I don't understand why the date is inside another object with a private field (starting with a $ sign). You can directly store the IDODate as you have mentioned in your question.

```
"createdTime": ISODate("2023-01-20T11:20:50.268Z")
```

without putting it inside an object.

If you did not do it in purpose, this could be a migration issue between when using mongoexport with a datetime filter using the `--query` option. This behaviour is documented [here](https://www.mongodb.com/docs/database-tools/mongoexport/#mongodb-binary-bin.mongoexport).

Your first query:

```
db.MyCollection.countDocuments({ createdTime: { $lt: ISODate("2023-02-01T00:00:00.000Z")} })
```

returns nothing, because createdTime is an object.

Your second query:

```
db.MyCollection.countDocuments({ "createdTime.$date": { $lt: ISODate("2023-02-01T00:00:00.000Z")}})
```

returns nothing because `createdTime.$date` cannot be directly be accessed in the query.  Fields with $ prefixed are not openly accesible in [Mongo](https://www.mongodb.com/docs/v5.0/core/dot-dollar-considerations/). What you have to do to make this work is to use an expression with a getField, that would enable you to access this.

For example, this query should give you the expected result.

```
db.MyCollection.countDocuments({$expr: {$lt: [{$getField: {$literal: "createdTime.$date"}}, ISODate("2023-02-01T00:00:00.000Z")]}})
```

But a better solution would be to keep createTime itself as an `ISODate`.

Comment: JSON doesn't have a date type, so in strict mode, mongodb uses `{'$date': ...}` to encapsulate the ISODate.